# Html page window close when click on any hyperlink of the page

Tags: html, hyperlink, window

I want a script that can make all hyperlinks of the page to open in a new a window, but as the links are opened in the new window the original page should close automatically.

Please help me with this problem and I would be very thankful

Answer (score 7):

To open a link in a new window:

```
<a href="yourlink.html" target="_blank">
```

To close a window:

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Close</a>
```

Comment: I know this post is old but anyone knows more about it because it's not working on the modern browser. I am getting the error Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.